# PostgreSQL query slows due to ORDER BY even with an index

Tags: postgresql, index, postgis

I have the following query to find offices that service a given area. When I run this query without the "ORDER BY" clause, it takes a less than 0.1 seconds. When I add the ORDER BY clause, it takes about 2 seconds on our data set.

```
SELECT off.provider_id, st_AsText(off.area), st_area(off.area)
FROM offices off
WHERE st_contains(off.area, :location)
ORDER BY st_area(off.area)
LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset;
```

When this first happened I realized, "Duh! there's no index"; ST_area is computing the area covered by a geospatial region and since I'm ordering on it, the optimizer must be checking all containment-filtered results at query time.

```
CREATE INDEX offices_st_area_idx
ON public.offices
USING btree
(st_area(area));
```

This addition had no effect on query time. Is there a faulty assumption I'm making here? Anybody have an idea of how I can speed this query up? I'd like to render this view without having to resort to a 'loading' page.

Comment: Sorry, didn't show it! Yes, we already have a spatial index, hence the very fast performance of the query without ORDER BY

Comment: I mean the index you create shoudnt be gist not btree?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I haven't used gists before but reading the docs they look like they are meant for custom data types. ST_Area() yields a floating point number and it seems like a btree is actually a fairly efficient way to work with it. Again, my inexperience with database indexes might be showing right now.

Comment: Can you show us your CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements, as well as row counts?  Also, the results of an EXPLAIN would help.

Comment: No answer, but the optimizer behavior will also depend on its estimate of how often the st_contains in the WHERE clause is TRUE. The optimizer will decide if the I/O cost is less going sequentially and then ordering, or scan through the index and rejecting most of them. Especially when it has to start with an unknown offset. What happens if you just put TRUE in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Please first run `ANALYZE offices` and try again. Then run both queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in front of the `SELECT` and append the explain results to this question.

Comment: Not an answer, but wondering what happens if you put the st_contains in a subquery, ie, select g.provider_id, g.geom, g.area from (
SELECT off.provider_id, st_AsText(off.area) as geom, st_area(off.area) as area
FROM offices off
WHERE st_contains(off.area, :location)) g
ORDER BY area
LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset;

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause the database takes any 10 records that meet your criteria and returns them. With `ORDER BY` it first finds all rows that meet criteria and then orders them.

You could try enabling [btree-gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) and then creating index on the spatial column and the area

```
CREATE INDEX offices_st_area_idx 
ON public.offices
USING gist (area, st_area(area));
```

But otherwise then that it's a normal question regarding performance and depends heavily on your data and server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Two independent indexes cannot be efficiently combined like that.

If your theory is correct that computing the area size is the slow step, then storing the area size in a column in the `offices` table would help a lot.  (You could use a trigger to automatically populate area size column from the area column).

The functional index you tried doesn't work, because that enables you to look up the row based on its area size, but you need to look up the area size based on the row.

On the other hand, if the true culprit is the time needed to completely run st_contains(off.area, :location), rather than stopping after the first 10, then that is much harder optimize.  To do that efficiently you usually have to resort to embedding some heuristics into your application code, rather than relying entirely on the database to come up with the optimum.

Also, I wonder what you are hiding from us behind the `:offset`.  If the :offset is 0, that is hugely different from an optimization perspective than if :offset is 180000.